# Count(*) of two sql statements where results are subset of another one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which has ~500 GBs of data and have two queries running on it.

```
-- Query 1
select Count(*) from table
where C1 = A

-- Query 2
select Count(*) from table
where C1 = A and C2 = B
```

I feel `Query 2` execution on whole table is un-necessary as the results are subset of `Query 1`. Is there any optimized way to first execute `Query 1` then run `Query 2` on the results of it and finally return Count of both the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS cnt_1,
    SUM(c2 = 'B') AS cnt_2
FROM yourTable
WHERE c1 = 'A';
```

The index `yourTable (c1, c2)` will improve.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Any such inter-query optimization would depend on the database, and I'm not familiar with any database that caches *intermediate* result sets.  In addition, such an optimization would be rendered useless if the underlying table changes -- and relational databases are designed to support changing data.

As a note:  the optimization would have to be very sophisticated, because the count returned by the first query has nothing to do with the count returned by the second.  You are thinking that the *rows* in the second are a subset of the first, but those rows are not actually returned.  Some databases -- including MySQL -- can cache result sets so the same query run later would use the cache.  However, MySQL is removing that support because of the complications it introduces.

If you want to phrase this as two queries, your best bet is an index on `t(c1, c2)`.  The index will be used for both queries and should be prety efficient.

Otherwise, use a single query.  Akina's solution is the best approach among the other answers because it filters before aggregating.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT
    SUM(C1 = A) AS cnt_1,
    SUM(C1 = A AND C2 = B) AS cnt_2
FROM yourTable;
```

The above works because MySQL happens to support summing boolean expressions.  On most other databases, you would use this version:

```sql
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN C1 = A THEN 1 END) AS cnt_1,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN C1 = A AND C2 = B THEN 1 END) AS cnt_2
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select SUM(CASE WHEN C1='A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), A_CNT
       SUM(CASE WHEN C1='A' AND C2='B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)B_CNT
from table
```